# Integrating Factor To Find General Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need a bit of help with integrating factors in differential equations in the following question. Bit confused how to rearrange to get the correct format needed: 
$$(1+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{4x^3y}{1-x^2} = 1$$

Use the integrating factor method to find the general solution and show that: $$y=\frac{k+3x-x^3}{3(1-x^4)}$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct form for an integrating factor is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x) \tag{1}$$
Where $\mu(x)=e^{\int P(x)~dx}$ is the integrating factor.

---

To obtain the correct form, divide both sides by $1+x^2$ to obtain:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{4x^3}{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)}y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
Expanding gives:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{4x^3}{1-x^4}y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
Putting it in the form of $(1)$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{4x^3}{x^4-1}y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
Hence, one should use the integrating factor:
$$\mu(x)=e^{\int \frac{4x^3}{x^4-1}~dx}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: I end up getting to (x^4 - 1)(dy/dx) + y = (x^2 - 1). I am not sure if this is right as i then have a problem integrating. This is after multiplying by the integrating factor.

Comment: Almost. If we multiply by:
$$\mu(x)=x^4-1$$
You should obtain:
$$(x^4-1)\frac{dy}{dx}+4x^3 y=x^2-1$$
Hence, it follows that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}((x^4-1)y)=x^2-1$$
Now, integrating both sides w.r.t $x$, you should obtain:
$$(x^4-1)y=\int (x^2-1)~dx$$
Which I am sure you can do.